# PRIx64 format macro not defined when compiling for armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, android-ndk, printf, armv7

To print `uint64_t` values, I am using the `PRIx64` macro.
This works on all platforms I tried (iOS, Windows, Linux, arm64 Android.)

But on 32 bit ARM Android, the macro does not seem to be available:

When compiling:

`LOGI("Cannot find %" PRIx64 " in wld.", item);`

I get:

`actors_pathing.cpp:234:25: error: expected ')'
                        LOGI("Cannot find %" PRIx64 " in wld.", item);
                                             ^`

arm64-v8a works fine, but armeabi-v7a does not.
Surely, 32 bit arm code should be able to print out 64 bit integers?

Using: NDK r13b (latest)

In Application.mk:
`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro needs to be defined when using PRIx64 format:

`-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
```